# Htaccess - routing to a php file

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I wish to route all address to my "router.php" file unless it is a file or directory. So far I have this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /router.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works for most urls such as:

`foo.dev/contact-us` uses the `router.php` file, and

`foo.dev/styles.css` uses the actual file as expected

However, when I go to `foo.dev` it goes to the `index.php` instead of the `router.php` page.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown us references `index.php`. It should be rewriting to `router.php`. We can only make guesses here without more information. My guess would be it IS rewriting to router.php as well, and it's your logic there which is going to index.php. Another possibility is you might have an old 301 redirect cached in your browser which is messing with your results if it's only with foo.dev. What about `foo.bar`, `crow.bar`, `bar`, and `foo.bar.baz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DirectoryIndex` directive:

```
DirectoryIndex router.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . router.php [L]
```